# How does the Goliath's "Natural Intimidator" interact with skill challenges where the use of intimidate automatically fails?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, social-stats, skill-challenge, goliath

If a goliath takes "Natural Intimidator" which notes that they only fail intimidate rolls if they fail by more than 5, and tries to intimidate someone in a skill challenge where intimidation "automatically fails" what happens?

1. The skill challenge is considered to be more specific than the feat, and therefore the intimidate check automatically fails and the player is pelted with dice.
2. The feat text is considered to be more specific than the skill challenge, and the character may attempt to intimidate normally, though her companions cannot.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case because it's an auto fail (even a 20 isn't going to get you a success here), it's going to be a fail.

In this case the DC of an intimidate check is ~infinity and thus any attempt is a failure of >5.

Comment: Well, it's a question of which is a more "specific" rule.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I think that autofailure is more specific than failure by >5.